# Export a private key associated with a self-signed certificate

Tags: salesforcedx, ssl, jwt

As part of our CI/CD with Azure, we were able to successfully authorize an Org using the JWT-Based Flow AS LONG AS we follow the steps [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_auth_jwt_flow.htm)

Every time we refresh our sandboxes, we have to go through the whole process again, which is a bit of a pain.

Question is, do you guys know if I can generate a server.key file (which is requried by the JWT Flow) from a self-signed certificate created within Salesforce, and not openssl?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

After you create a self-signed cert in SF, you can export the keypair (private key/public key) as a JKS keystore. You can then [extract the private key](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore) from the keystore via either `keytool` (ships with Java runtime) or OpenSSL.

Comment: Thanks, @identigral!

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped resolve your query.