# Issue getting public key, getting 400 Bad Request using JWT+OAuth while integrating salesforce with Box.com

Tags: apex, oauth2, httprequest, jwt, certificates

I am trying to get access token from box.com. For this I created a custom app that uses OAuth and JWT. I have also created a self signed certificate in salesforce. This self signed certificate is used in getting the assertion which is later used as request body (to box.com). However, I am getting a "**400 Bad Request**" status message.
The code to get access token is shown below:

```
Map<String, String> extraClaims= new Map<String,String>();
        extraClaims.put('box_sub_type', 'enterprise');
        Auth.Jwt jwt = new Auth.Jwt();
        jwt.setIss(oAuthClientId); //oAuthClientId and clientSecret is given by box.com custom app
        jwt.setAud('https://api.box.com/oauth2/token');
        jwt.setSub(enterpriseID); //enterpriseId of my box.com account
        jwt.setAdditionalClaims(extraClaims);
        jwt.setValidityLength(60);

        Auth.JWS jws = new Auth.JWS(jwt, certificateName); 
        String assertion = jws.getCompactSerialization();
        Http http = new http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint(authenticationUrl);
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String body = 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer'+
                        '&client_id='+oAuthClientId+
                        '&client_secret='+oAuthClientSecret+
                        '&assertion='+assertion;
        request.setBody(body);

        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
        //response returns 400 Bad Request
```

In box.com there is an option to add and manage Public Keys. I am not sure on what i should insert here. From salesforce, I just downloaded the self signed certificate(crt file) and copied its content and pasted in box.com Add and Manage public keys section. However, It did not work. 
The content start as

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIG+DCCBOCgAwIBA...
.......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I also tried to export the certificate as jks file, put a password while exporting. I then used the jks file to PEM file. I then copied the content of PEM file in box.com as well(I am not sure, If i followed the correct steps). However that also didnot work.

So, plz help me on getting the access taken from box.com? What did i miss. Any steps on getting the public key from self signed certificate.

Comment: Did u try this one to get private key: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/275775/export-a-private-key-associated-with-a-self-signed-certificate

Comment: @Ayub Yes, I tried and i was able get a public key but that did not work. So, I am thinking the approach i followed were wrong. So, looking for soln.

Comment: But you need to use the private key and sign using this key while sending request from apex. Public key you have alrready uploaded in box.

Comment: I've prototyped successfully. I'm adding as answer shortly.

Comment: @lambad did ever work this for you? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did give a try and successfully able to get the access token. During this, I got bunch of things that I fixed as below:

- App in Box should be admin authorized
- Signing the request using JWS does not work for some reason. I need
  to build the payload by myself without using jwt
- Using Datetime.now for 'exp' does not work - may be because of gmt
  conversion. So I need to use JWT to generate this.

Here is the code, replace the data accordigly:

```
public class BoxAuthenticationUsingJWT{
    //BoxAuthenticationUsingJWT.connectWithBox();
    public static void connectWithBox(){
        String clientId = '6651wi15q83qvav53jznsgdswuxxxxxx';
        String clientSecret = '1DTfOrIQF0M2YxSKmKmk9jY5abxxxxxx';
        String endpoint = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token';
        String iss = clientId;
        String aud = endpoint;
        String sub = '334200xxx'; //Enterprise Id

        //Long exp = DateTime.now().addhours(-8).addSeconds(30).getTime(); // Datetime.now is returning fiff time than what need JWT token 
        Auth.Jwt jwt = new Auth.Jwt();
        jwt.setValidityLength(60);
        String jwtRequestd = jwt.toJSONString();
        Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jwtRequestd);
        Long exp = (Long)m.get('exp');
        system.debug(jwtRequestd);

        system.debug(jwt.getValidityLength());
        // Start constructing the header and claims
        String jwtHeader = '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256"}';

        String jwtClaims = '{"iss":"' + iss +'","jti":"'+UserInfo.getUserID()+'","box_sub_type":"enterprise","sub":"' + sub + '","aud":"' + aud + '","exp":' + exp + '}';
        system.debug(jwtClaims);
        String jwtRequest = System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(jwtHeader)).replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_') + '.' + System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(jwtClaims)).replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');

        String signature = System.encodingUtil.base64Encode(Crypto.signWithCertificate('RSA-SHA256', Blob.valueOf(jwtRequest), 'jwt')).replace('+', '-').replace('/', '_');
        String signedJwtRequest = jwtRequest + '.' + signature;

        // The JWT is fully constructed, now it's time to make the call to get the access token.

        String payload = 'grant_type=' + System.EncodingUtil.urlEncode('urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer', 'UTF-8');
        payload += '&client_id='+clientId+'&client_secret='+clientSecret;
        payload += '&assertion=' + signedJwtRequest;


        Http httpObj = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res;


        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setBody(payload);

        res = httpObj.send(req);

        System.debug(res.getBody());

    }

}
```

> For newbie, I've added this piece with more details and steps here:
>   https://sfdcian.com/box-jwt-authentication-in-salesforce-using-apex/

Comment: Not going to downvote...but the asker's code is better - it correctly uses out of the box functionality rather then reinventing the wheel. Signing the JWT [does work](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/281049/using-jwt-when-calling-out-from-salesforce-to-third-party-api) out of the box. The asker's issue has to do with correctly configuring Box side.

Comment: Thanks for not downvoting. But it's not like I just picked this approach by choice - I did spent hours to analyze - in this case something is happening - JWS signed is not working  while Crypto.sign is working with BOX. May be I need to do some more research or may be diff thread of discussion!